# difference of *var[n] with (*var)[n]

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I have a question regarding the difference between `char *<variable>[6]` and `char (*<variable>)[6]`.
I was making a code for an exercise which asks to input and store 6 strings and later turn each into an integer. My plan was to make an array of strings to store them and I did `char *<variable>[6] = malloc(7*sizeof(char));` but an error showed up saying ' array initializer must be an initializer list ' but when i changed it to `char (*<variable>)[6] = malloc(7*sizeof(char));` it can work properly. What is the difference between `(*<variable>)[6]` and `*<variable>[6]` ?

My code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char (*sixString)m[6] = (char *) malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        printf("Input for the Number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", sixString[i]);
        //fgets(sixString[i], 100, stdin);
        printf("%s\n", sixString[i]);
        sum = sum + atoi(sixString[i]);
    }
    float average = (float)sum/6 ;
    printf("Sum is: %d\nAverage is: %.2f\n", sum, average);

    free(sixString);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *<variable>[6]
```

is a 6-element array of `char*`.

```
char (*<variable>)[6]
```

is a pointer to 6-element array of `char`.

Your code allocated insufficient number of bytes. You should use

```
    char (*sixString)[6] = malloc(7 * sizeof(char[6]));
```

or

```
    char (*sixString)[6] = malloc(7 * sizeof(*sixString));
```

instead of

```
    char (*sixString)m[6] = (char *) malloc(7 * sizeof(char));
```

(size is fixed and the extra `m` is removed)

Note that then you allocate 7 elements of `char[6]`, but you use only 6 of them in the loop.
Allocating extra elements may look inefficient, but cause less harm than allocating insufficient size.

Comment: Thankyou so much, this clears my concept again, pointers and dynamic memory are really blendering my brain.